# How to animate font-size on mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have issues animating the font-size on element mouseenter:

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qjUc5/)

**HTML**:

```
<p>Hello!</p>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
("p").mouseenter(function () {
    ("p").animate({
        "font-size": "50px"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

`("p")` should be `$("p")`
You're missing an `});`
and you're not using the jQuery library

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("p").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({"font-size": "50px"});
    });
});
```

[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/qjUc5/2/)

A slightly nicer way to write the same would be:

```
jQuery(function($) {  // DOM ready shorthand

    $("p").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate({ fontSize : 50 });
    });

});
```

<sub>Remember to always keep reference to the targeted Object Element `$(this)` to get the desired result.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

you must use $ sign in your code
try this code.
i tested.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("p").mouseenter(function () {
                $(this).animate({
                    "font-size": "50px"
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the }); and $ signs, and the jQuery library in your fiddle.

**http://jsfiddle.net/qjUc5/5/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).animate({fontSize:"30px"});
  });
});
```